# Yet Another multithreaded FIFO queue written in C++17

Tags: c++, thread-safety, queue, c++17

Here, I have written a simple FIFO multithreaded queue with following features (if I have implemented correctly):

- Thread safe
- Supports multiple container types (given that they provide some function) via template meta-programming
- queue size can be limited
- has several policies for enqueuing items (such as discard first, discard last, discard all or discard none)
- Supports time-outed waiting

That's all. It would be great if you could review it.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

namespace {

template <typename Container>
class multithreaded_fifo_queue {
public:

    multithreaded_fifo_queue() {
    }

    // thread-safe.
    void has_size_limit(bool b) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            has_size_limit_ = b;
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

    // thread-safe.
    bool has_size_limit() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
        return has_size_limit_;
    }

    // thread-safe.
    void size_limit(size_t sz) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            size_limit_ = sz;
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

    // thread-safe.
    size_t size_limit() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
        return size_limit_;
    }

    // thread-safe.
    size_t size() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
        return c_.size();
    }

    // thread-safe.
    Container &container() {
        return c_;
    }

    // thread-safe.
    const Container &container() const {
        return c_;
    }

    // thread-safe. tries to dequeue an object from the queue. if there is no
    // object enqueued, returns false immediately.
    bool dequeue(auto &t) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            if (c_.size() == 0)
                return false;
            t = std::move(c_.front());
            c_.pop_front();
            return true;
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

    // thread-safe. dequeues an object from the queue. if there is no object
    // enqueued, waits until an object is enqueued.
    void dequeue_wait(auto &t) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            cv_.wait(lock, [this] { return !c_.empty(); });
            t = std::move(c_.front());
            c_.pop_front();
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

    // thread-safe. dequeues an object from the queue. if there is no object
    // enqueued, waits until an object is enqueued. it has an additional
    // timeout.
    template <class Rep, class Period>
    bool dequeue_wait_for(
        auto &t,
        const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& rel_time) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            if (wait_for(lock, rel_time, [this] { return !c_.empty(); })) {
                t = std::move(c_.front());
                c_.pop_front();
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
        return true;
    }

    // thread-safe. dequeues an object from the queue. if there is no object
    // enqueued, waits until an object is enqueued. it has an additional
    // deadline.
    template <class Clock, class Duration>
    bool dequeue_wait_until(
        auto &t,
        const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& deadline) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            if (wait_until(lock, deadline, [this] { return !c_.empty(); })) {
                t = std::move(c_.front());
                c_.pop_front();
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
        return true;
    }

    enum discard_policy {
        no_discard,
        discard_all,
        discard_first,
        discard_last
    };

    // thread-safe. tries to enqueue an object to the queue. if maximum size
    // is reached, returns false immediately.
    bool enqueue(auto &&t, discard_policy discard = no_discard) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            if (has_size_limit_) {
                if (size_limit_ == c_.size()) {
                    switch (discard) {
                    case no_discard:
                        return false;
                        break;
                    case discard_all:
                        c_.clear();
                        break;
                    case discard_first:
                        c_.pop_front();
                        break;
                    case discard_last:
                        c_.pop_back();
                        break;
                    }
                    c_.push_back(std::move(t));
                }
                else {
                    c_.push_back(std::move(t));
                }
            }
            else {
                c_.push_back(std::move(t));
            }
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
        return true;
    }

    // thread-safe. enqueues an object to the queue. if maximum size is reached
    // waits until an object is dequeued.
    void enqueue_wait(auto &&t) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            wait(
                lock,
                [this] { return !has_size_limit_ || c_.size() < size_limit_; });
            c_.push_back(std::move(t));
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

    // thread-safe. enqueues an object to the queue. if maximum size is reached
    // waits until an object is dequeued. it has an additional timeout.
    template <class Rep, class Period>
    bool enqueue_wait_for(
        auto &&t,
        const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& rel_time) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            if (wait_for(
                lock,
                rel_time,
                [this] { return !has_size_limit_ || c_.size() < size_limit_; })) {
                c_.push_back(std::move(t));
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
        return true;
    }

    // thread-safe. enqueues an object to the queue. if maximum size is reached
    // waits until an object is dequeued. it has an additional deadline.
    template <class Clock, class Duration>
    bool enqueue_wait_until(
        auto &&t,
        const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& deadline) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            if (wait_until(
                lock,
                deadline,
                [this]
                { return !has_size_limit_ || c_.size() < size_limit_; })) {
                c_.push_back(std::move(t));
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        cv_.notify_all();
        return true;
    }

private:
    Container c_;

    bool has_size_limit_ {false};
    size_t size_limit_ {1000};


    mutable std::mutex mtx_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
};

};
```

**EDIT** I fixed const-qualifiers issue with `mutable` keyword.

Comment: Seeing questions about multithreaded queues always reminds me of this talk by Fedor Pikus: https://youtu.be/1obZeHnAwz4?t=48m. I've got no audio right now so can't locate the exact moment, but somewhere around the 48min mark he talks about how it makes little to no sense to try and order objects in a multithreaded queue. He also explains the design of a fast multithreaded queue design based on that principle. Worth the watch! That's not to say your design is bad, btw.

Answer (score 2):

#### Excessive notifications

At least at first glance, it looks like you've included some `notify_all` calls that don't really accomplish anything, such as when the client sets a size limit.

#### Consider using utility classes

Just for example, you have an optional size limit. At least at first glance, it looks like this could be more cleanly implemented as a `std::optional<size_t>`.

#### Policy Based Design

For the discard policy, I'd at least consider using policy-based design. That is, instead of having an enumeration, and a switch inside the class to determine the correct action based on the enumeration, create (tiny) classes to implement the policies, and pass one of them as a template parameter:

```
namespace policy {

    template <class C>
    struct discard_none {
        bool operator()(C &container) const { 
            return false;
        }
    };

    template <class C>
    struct discard_all {
        bool operator()(C &container) const { 
            container.clear();
            return true;
        }
    };

    template <class C>
    struct discard_last {
        bool operator()(C &container) const { 
            container.pop_back();
            return true;
        }
    };

    template <class C>
    struct discard_first {
        bool operator()(C &container) const { 
           container.pop_front();
           return true;
        }
    };

    // ...
}

template <class T, class discard = policy::discard_none>
class queue {
    // ...
    bool enqueue(auto &&t) {
        if (has_size_limit_ && size_limit_ == c_.size()) {
            if (!discard()(c_))
                return false;
             c_.push_back(t);
         }
         cv_.notify_all();
         return true;
    }
```

This allows (for example) adding a different discard policy in the future, if you want (e.g., you could add priorities to items, and query them to find the least important, and discard it).

On the other hand, this also represents a change in the basic design, at least as I've written it here. Rather than specifying a discard policy each time you enqueue, this specifies a policy for the entire duration of a particular queue's existence. Unless you really need that extra flexibility, specifying it as a policy is *probably* a win.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Suppose a thread is waiting on enqueue_wait(...) due to full size, if another thread changes the size limit, and increases the size, I want this thread to be waken up.

Comment: Utility classes and policy based design are really good suggestions, I will consider using them.